# List folders of Classes in C++ PDB using DIA SDK

Tags: c++, c#-3.0, debug-symbols, pdb-files, dia-sdk

I am working on a profiling tool in C#. It analyses **C++ PDB** files using **DIA SDK** and lists all classes, functions, fields etc.

I would like to know the **folder names of the classes** and list classes, functions etc folder wise. I have seen all the properties/functions on IDiaSymbol, but could not find anything on the folder name of the class.

**How to get folder name of the classes in C++ PDB using DIA SDK?**

Thanks

Raghu

Answer (score 0):

Is it the folder name containing the .cpp source file containing your classes? **IDiaSourceFile.get_filename()**  does return the full pathname of your source file.  Is it what you're after?